# How to pass data between two contexts in MVC with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

In my MVC app with Entity Framework, I have 2 contexts.  One is for my business data (`DemoPoolEntities`) and the other is for the ASPNet identity data such as ASPNetUsers and ASPNetRoles(`ApplicationDbCcontext`).  The data is all stored in the same database.  I have them split into two different models in my project `DemoPoolModels.cs` and `IdentityModels.cs` respectively.

I need to pass data from the ApplicationDbContext to my DemoPoolEntities context in order to display them on some of my views.

For example I have a `Customer` object in my db.  `Customer` is in the `DemoPoolEntities` context but has a foreign key relationship to `AspNetUser` which is in the `ApplicationDbContext`.  I need to display this `ASPNetUser` in my `Index` view from the `Customer` controller this will show which user the customer belongs to basically.

However, when I go to the view I keep getting the following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: 'An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.'

'Inner Exception
SqlException: Invalid column name 'AspNetUser_Id'.'
```

**CustomerController.cs**

```
// GET: Customers
        [Authorize(Roles = "Admin, User")]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {

            return View(db.Customers.ToList());
        }
```

**Customer View (Index.cshtml)**

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserId)
```

**In my Customer Model**

```
[StringLength(128)]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
```

**IdentityModels.cs**

```
namespace DemoPool.Models
{
    // You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your ApplicationUser class, please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594 to learn more.
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext()
            : base("DemoPoolEntities", throwIfV1Schema: false)
        {
        }

        public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
        {
            return new ApplicationDbContext();
        }
    }
}
```

**DemoPoolModels.cs**

```
public partial class DemoPoolEntities : DbContext
    {
        public DemoPoolEntities()
            : base("name=DemoPoolEntities")
        {
        }
public virtual DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.CompanyName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.FirstName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.LastName)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.PhoneNumber)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Email)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Address1)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Address2)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.City)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.State)
                .IsUnicode(false);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
                .Property(e => e.Zip)
                .IsUnicode(false);
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>()
                .HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>()
                .HasKey<string>(r => r.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().HasKey(r => new { r.RoleId, r.UserId });
}
```

So my question is how can I get the `ASPNetUser` info that is referenced by `Customer` in the `Customer` view when they are in two different contexts and is there a different way I should be doing this?

Comment: **See the inner exception for details** . Did you ?

Comment: Yes, sorry just added.

Comment: Inner Exception
SqlException: Invalid column name 'AspNetUser_Id'.

Comment: Couldn't you do some logic that gets the information out of one context and then use whatever it is when looking through the other context?

Comment: I ended up creating a model for ASPNetUser so that I could access it.  Seems to work.  Just added it as the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by creating a model for the EF object that I was trying to access.  So in this case I created a model for ASPNetUser.  This seems to work.